# SQL Query getting a list of items from table based on other table column value?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have these 2 tables:
**BluePrint**:

```
ID| BlueprintID| CarID
```

**Car**:

```
ID, Name, Color
```

I need to get all the cars based on `blueprintID`.
I am using SQLLite.

Thanks

Comment: what did you try and what are the errors you got ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to join one table to the other.

`SELECT c.ID, c.Name, c.Color FROM CAR c JOIN BLUEPRINT b ON b.CarID = c.ID WHERE b.BlueprintID = [YOURBLUEPRINTID]`

I have given both tables an alias, it makes it easier especially when you have lots of fields.  If a field with the same name appears in both tables and you don't specify which table by using something like `c.Name` or Car.Name` you will get an ambiguous field name error.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with either a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM Car
WHERE ID IN (SELECT CarID
             FROM BluePrint
             WHERE BlueprintID = ?)
```

or a join:

```
SELECT Car.*
FROM Car
JOIN BluePrint ON Car.ID = BluePrint.CarID
WHERE BlueprintID = ?
```

(If it is possible to have multiple blueprints for one car, the second query needs `SELECT DISTINCT`.)

Answer (score 0):

SELECT c.*,B.BlueprintID FROM CAR C,BluePrint B
WHERE  C.ID=B.CarID

Comment: You should stop using these kinds of joins  Aaron Bertrand wrote a good article on it  https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins